# Converge API Error Code 4000

Tags: api, axios, vuex

I am attempting to POST to the Converge Demo API and I am getting a 4000 error. Message is "The VirtualMerchant ID was not supplied in the authorization request."

I am using axios inside Vuex. I am attempting to make the post from Vuex for now since it's demo. I am throwing it up https with TLSv1.2_2018.

Here's the simplified version of the code I am using.

```
    let orderDetails = {
      ssl_merchant_id:'******',
      ssl_user_id:'***********',
      ssl_pin: '****...',
      ssl_transaction_type: 'ccsale',
      ssl_amount: '5.47',
      ssl_card_number: '4124939999999990',
      ssl_cvv2cvc2: '123',
      ssl_exp_date: '1219',
      ssl_first_name: 'No Named Man',
      ssl_test_mode: true
    }

    let orderJSON = JSON.stringify(orderDetails)

    let config = {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }

     axios.post('https://api.demo.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do', orderJSON, config)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res', res.data)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('e', e)
      })
```

Has anyone solved this and/or able to share some wisdom?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are sending the values the wrong way and that's why you receive the message of a missing parameter. The endpoing process.do expects to receive a key value pairs formatted request

```
ssl_merchant_id=******&ssl_user_id=***********&ssl_pin=****&ssl_transaction_type=ccsale&ssl_amount=5.47&ssl_card_number=4124939999999990&ssl_cvv2cvc2=123&ssl_exp_date=1219&ssl_first_name=No Named Man&ssl_test_mode=true
```

> From Converge website (https://developer.elavon.com)
>
> Converge currently supports two different ways to integrate:
>
> Key value pairs formatted request using process.do (for a single transaction) or processBatch.do (for a batch file) with the following
>   syntax: ssl_name_of_field = value of field (example: ssl_amount =
>   1.00)
>
> Or
>
> XML formatted request using processxml.do (for a single transaction) or accountxml.do (for a Admin request), the transaction
>   data formatted in XML syntax must include all supported transaction
>   elements nested between one beginning and ending element , the
>   data is contained within the xmldata variable.